# Alocacao dinamica e ponteiros em Lua

Tags: c, lua, struct, alocação

Gostaria de saber como faço alocação dinâmica e ponteiro de uma estrutura em Lua, tenho a seguinte instrução em C que preciso passar para Lua;

```
typedef struct ilha {
    char name;
    struct ilha *prox1, *prox2, *prox3;
} *Ilha;

Ilha aloc(Ilha x) {
    x = malloc(sizeof(struct ilha));
    return x;
}

int main() {
    A = aloc(A);
    B = aloc(B);
    B->name = "Hello Word";
    A->prox1 = B;
    printf("%d", A->prox1->name);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Não precisas de passar uma cópia do ponteiro para a função de alocação
  a função `aloc()` pode apenas devolver o ponteiro sem receber nada
- Esqueceste-te de definir `A` e `B` na função `main()`
- Verifica o resultado do `malloc()`
- Não confundas `char` com `char[]` (ou `char*`) nem com `int`
  no `printf()` usa `"%d"` com `int`s; `%c` com `char`s e `%s` com *strings* (`char[]` ou `char*`)

Depois de olhar para estes pontos, alterei o teu programa para:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ilha {
    char name[100];
    struct ilha *prox1, *prox2, *prox3;
};

struct ilha *aloc(void) {
    struct ilha *x = malloc(sizeof *x);
    return x;
}

int main() {
    struct ilha *A = aloc();
    if (A == NULL) exit(1);
    struct ilha *B = aloc();
    if (B == NULL) exit(2);
    strcpy(B->name, "Hello Word");
    A->prox1 = B;
    printf("%s\n", A->prox1->name);

    return 0;
}
```

Em vez de definires o `name` como um array de 100 caracteres podes definir como um ponteiro para char, e posteriormente fazeres o `malloc()` necessario e `strcpy()`.